# Problema con interfaces en delphi

Tags: delphi, 2d

Tenia un juego de naves 2D , que venia haciendolo hace tiempo atrás, y lo uso para practicar todo tipo de contenido que voy aprendiendo de programación.
Dibujo todo en FMX, uso bitmaps, en un bucle dibujo todo y tiro el frame al final, etc.

Hace un tiempo arranque a practicar **interfaces**. Y si bien mi juego es bastante simple por el momento, ya el codigo empezó a crecer una barbaridad, y es un lio para agregar efectos y demas, porque todo es un desastre al no tener un buen diseño.

Entonces empecé a usar interfaces para poder ir modularizando un poco.  Y si bien creo que son una maravilla cuando las aprendí por arriba, ahora que quiero profundizar me estoy volviendo loco literal. **No entiendo como usarlas bien!!**

**Algo sencillo :**

```
IEntityBox = interface
        procedure SetX (Value : single);
        procedure SetY (Value : single);
        procedure SetH (Value : integer);
        procedure SetW (Value : integer);

        function GetX : single;
        function GetY : single;
        function GetH : integer;
        function GetW : integer;

        property X : single read GetX write SetX;
        property Y : single read GetY write SetY;
        property H : integer read GetH write SetH;
        property W : integer read GetW write SetW;
    end;

IEntityGraphics = interface
        function GetSpriteModel: TBitmap;
        procedure SetSpriteModel(Value: TBitmap);
        property SpriteModel: TBitmap read GetSpriteModel write SetSpriteModel;
  end;
```

**Ahora creo una clase :**

```
type
    Shoot = class(TInterfacedObject,IEntityBox,IEntityGraphics)
    private
    // Campos privados para IEntityBox
    FX : Single;
    FY : Single;
    FH : Integer;
    FW : Integer;


    // Campo privado para IEntityGraphics
    FSpriteModel: TBitmap;

    // Implementación de IEntityBox
    function GetX: Single;
    function GetY: Single;
    function GetH: Integer;
    function GetW: Integer;
    procedure SetX(Value: Single);
    procedure SetY(Value: Single);
    procedure SetH(Value: Integer);
    procedure SetW(Value: Integer); 

    // Implementación de IEntityGraphics
    function GetSpriteModel: TBitmap;
    procedure SetSpriteModel(Value: TBitmap);

    public
    property X: Single read GetX write SetX;
    property Y: Single read GetY write SetY;
    property H: Integer read GetH write SetH;
    property W: Integer read GetW write SetW;

    property SpriteModel: TBitmap read GetSpriteModel write SetSpriteModel;
  end;
```

Y ahora en otra clase, tengo por ejemplo este procedimiento :

```
procedure TBase.UpdateGraphics(Model : IEntityGraphics ; BoxModel : IEntityBox);
begin
          Core.SGGraphics.DrawModel(Model, BoxModel, 0, 0, 1);
end;
```

Este ultimo procedimiento, llama al metodo de una clase, donde tengo las rutinas de dibujado , etc.

Las funciones , los metodo setters,getters y eso esta todo implementado. No hay error alli. Pero me salta un error de AccessViolation en tiempo de ejecucion al utilizar esta metodologia. Si yo utilizo solo clases, no tengo el error. Pero al intentar utilizar esto con interfaces como parámetros me vuela en tiempo de ejecucion.

Edito, porque me olvide de poner el llamado al metodo, y aclaro que **tampoco entiendo bien como usarlas**, entiendo el concepto de las mismas pero se que esta no es ideal :

```
UpdateGraphics(Disparo,Disparo);
```

Disparo es una Instancia de TSHOOT, que implementa las interfaces anteriores. Instanciado correctamente, y tambien su propiedad SpriteModel, instanciada correctamente y asignada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezo alguna ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: El error de AccessViolation es porque estás accediendo a una dirección de memoria incorrecta (por ejemplo al intentar utilizar un objeto no creado). Es difícil saber más, porque el código que está provocando el error no está puesto. La definición de las clases y los interfaces perece correcta, pero para detectar el error habría que ver cómo las estás utilizando.
Si no puedes añadirlo aquí, ejecuta paso a paso hasta la línea que provoca el error y revisa que todo lo que usas esté creado.

Comment: Las referencias a interfaces, de objetos que heredan de TInterfacedObject, liberan automáticamente el objeto que implementa las interfaces si el contador de referencias llega a cero (modelo conocido como ARC, de Automatic Reference Count). Por ello, por regla general, con estos, no almacenas referencias a objetos, sino solo a las interfaces. Esto puede provocar el AV que estás viendo. El tema es algo largo para una respuesta de SO, pero la escribiría si comprobamos que ese es el origen del mismo.